# Is sentence No3 a fragment that needs to be attatched to No2?

Tags: grammar

Have you seen the movie "Dirty Dancing"?

It's a 1987 American romantic drama, a feel‐good film for people of all ages.

Is the above sentence now a comma splice?

Comment: If by 'needs to be attached' you really mean "Aaagh! A dreaded sentence fragment. I was taught at school they're ungrammatical!" I'm afraid it would be far better to ditch that entrenched viewpoint. As soon as possible. Judiciously used, sentence fragments are allowable, often laudable, in informal writing. They can add punch. _It wouldn't be wrong to use a comma or dash after 'drama', but it works well as it is._ [See previous threads on 'sentence fragments' / 'crots'.]

Comment: eg [Fragments in speech vs fragments in novels](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/fragments-in-speech-vs-fragments-in-novels/446060#446060);  [What do you call a subordinate clause that follows its main clause but is incomplete](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172521/what-do-you-call-a-subordinate-clause-that-follows-its-main-clause-but-is-wrongl/172526#172526).